# Looking for a more Pythonic way to grab text from individual tweets

Tags: python, twitter

I'm trying to grab just the text of the first 50 tweets for a certain word/hashtag taken as input by the user.  I tried writing for-loops to do this, for example:

```
for i in range(1,50):
 self.status_texts[i] = (statuses[i])
    for i in range(1,50):
     self.tweets = self.status_texts[i]['text']
```

but it always comes back with a `KeyError`.  I'm basically looking for a way to combine the `self.status_texts = (statuses[0])` action and the action that retrieves the text, currently in the return.

Is this possible?  Can any of you give me any tips on where to get started?

```
twitter_api = twitter.Twitter(auth=auth)


q = input('What to search for?')
q = str(q)
count = 50
search_results = twitter_api.search.tweets(q=q, count=count)
statuses = search_results['statuses']
f = open('twitter.txt', 'w')

class Tweeter():

    def puretweets(self):
        self.status_texts = (statuses[0])
        self.status_texts1 = (statuses[1])
        self.status_texts2 = (statuses[2])

        return self.status_texts['text'], self.status_texts1['text'], self.status_texts2['text']
```

Comment: Regarding the code snippets: the former is invalid (is the second loop nested or not) and it is not clear why you included the second snippet. thx

Comment: @JohnMee yes the second loop is nested - included the second snippet to show how I'm currently accomplishing what I'm looking for a more elegant solution to. cheers

Comment: So basically you want to return a tuple of length `50` which contains the text of tweets ?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to get just the text to go into the tuple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far I guess, You want to return a tuple with all the tweets text stored in it, which can be easily done as:

```
def puretweets(self):
    # self.status_texts = (statuses[0])
    # self.status_texts1 = (statuses[1])
    # self.status_texts2 = (statuses[2])
    return (statuses[i] for i in range(1, 50))
```

Or simply

```
def puretweets(self):
    return statuses[1:50]
```